Angular does not retrieve objects nor messages from django endpoints on docker
Trying to deploy Django Rest Framework and Angular with Docker.
I have 3 containers: django, db and angular (with nginx on it)
The deployment is completed and I can open localhost:80 and see my angular components.
However, the component service is calling to http://localhost:8000/api/sensores/ to retrieve all the objects in the db (I made sure there is one object there, which I created from django shell, and reviewed it on the db container) and it is getting an error. Two logs appear on Chrome console:

Error al obtener sensores: ct {headers: e, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/sensores/', ok: false, …}error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: 'error', …}headers: e {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8000/api/sensores/: 0 Unknown Error"name: "HttpErrorResponse"ok: falsestatus: 0statusText: "Unknown Error"url: "http://localhost:8000/api/sensores/"[[Prototype]]: zn ...
polyfills-FFHMD2TL.js:1

GET http://localhost:8000/api/sensores/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

From exec console in my angular-nginx container, I can make this:
curl http://api:8000/api/sensores/

And get the object I'm looking for, but angular can't do it itself.
Here my docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  angular:
    container_name: angular-nginx
    build: ./hello
      # context: ./hello
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./hello/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro  
      - ./hello/dist/hello/browser:/usr/share/nginx/html
    depends_on:
      - db

  api:
    build:
      context: ./django
    command: gunicorn helloDocker.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./django:/app
    expose:
      - "8000"
    environment:
      - DEBUG=False
      - DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=your_secret_key
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5432/vituclim
    depends_on:
      - db

  # Servicio de base de datos
  db:
    container_name: postgre
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: vituclim
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  db_data:

This is my nginx.conf, in angular project folder:
user nginx;
worker_processes auto; 
pid /var/run/nginx.pid; 

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types; 
    default_type  application/octet-stream; 

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    server {
        listen 80;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;  
            index index.html;            

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://api:8000/;o
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }

    }
}

For the last config for /api/ directions, it doesn't work with or without it.
I expect to call the component service and retrieve a list of objects (Sensor) to show on the HTML. The TS & HTML of the component are fine, as the problem comes from the service.
I suppose the problem comes from angular, or nginx configuration. But I can't see it clearly.

Remove the trailing slash from your proxy_pass directive parameter; leave it as follows: proxy_pass http://api:8000; Adding the trailing slash, you are removing the /api prefix from your resulting request, which is most likely not what you want. Read the proxy_pass directive documentation for the details.

@IvanShatsky it is not working either.
It throws ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED and "Http failure response for http://api:8000/api/sensores/: 0 Unknown Error"

You should make your API call as /api/sensores/; when you do it as http://localhost:8000/api/sensores/, you are pointing API call to the end user local computer. This works on your dev computer, but will never work from any other computer. Your request should be handled by nginx itself which is in turn will proxy it to your Django container due to the location /api/ { proxy_pass http://api:8000; } block.

Usually some environment variable (e.g. API_URL) is defined as http://localhost:8000/api/ for your development configuration and as just /api/ for your production configuration (see this answer); next, you are using it a way like this.http.get(API_URL + 'sensors/')

The component service should call http://localhost:80/api/sensores/
Nginx is running on angular-nginx container in which you opened and mapped the port 80.
As per your nginx config, it will handle the redirect to your server and will be able to do that because you exposed the port 8000 (in api service) to other docker containers (and this is why you can curl http://api:8000/api/sensores/ inside nginx container).
Quick and simple explanation to anyone who's wondering:
ports config opens a port on "your machine" and maps it to a port in the container you are configuring. In this case, for example, it opens the port 80 and maps it to the port 80 of the container angular-nginx.
expose config, instead, opens a port on the container you are configuring, but it will be reachable from another container only.
